# How can I use the 'subscribe' to receive more msgs with predis?

Tags: php, redis

I have 2 clients and want to chat with each other, both do publish and subscribe.

But as you know that PHP-process can not stay for long and I can't receive the further msg using the command subscribe in predis.

Also, there's no doc for us to check, How can I use the command correctly? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about durability of messages send via publish (in respect with your php processes) then instead of publish/subscribe you can use `brpop` together with `lpush`.

That way you will have durable "message queue" and you will not lost any messages. Instead of publishing you will simply `lpush` to list and on the worker side you will wait for messages via `brpop`.

Comment: This may be a nice way on which there are only 2 ends and the message will be deleted after checking~ and for that I didn't describe it well because it shoule be more ends~ And now I changed to zset and use ajax longpolling to check the modifications and the msg won't disappear as you know, they are in the sets~ Thanks a lot and though I can't make it with the pub/sub, I still want to close the question for real-time sys may do unsuitable for the PHP :)

Comment: If you are worried about lost jobs, you can easily use `brpoplpush` to remove them from waiting queue and put them to some "working to finish processing" queue. Also my solution supports multiple producers and consumer. Only and main difference is that in publish/subscribe every subscriber gets all messages where in list solution, only one consumer gets one message. If that is problem you can have multiple queues, one per consumer.

Comment: Thanks~ That time I changed to other datastruct to imitate this and later may take time to learn to this the publish/subscribe~